# Is there any example that we can apply AM-GM Inquality combined with squeeze theorem?

Tags: limits, analysis, inequality

We have AM-GM Inquality:
$$
\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}{n} \geq \sqrt[n]{x_1x_2\cdots x_n}.
$$
And we also have squeeze theorem:

Suppose $f(x)≤g(x)≤h(x)$ for all $x$ in an open interval about $a$ (except possibly at $a$ itself) and $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}{f(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}{h(x)}=L$, then we can obtain $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}{g(x)}=L$.

We know that if sequence {$x_n$} converges to a limit as n tends to infinity, say $L$, then its arithmetic mean and geometric mean will both converge to $L$ as well. Now I wonder if there is any example, say a sequence or something else that we can apply both of the theorems above together, i.e.
$$
\sqrt[n]{x_1x_2\cdots x_n} \leq \text{Something} \leq \frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}{n} \Rightarrow \lim{\text{Something}}=L.
$$

Answer (score 2):

One can always contrive some examples I suppose, though they may not necessarily be the easiest way to find the required limit. For e.g. suppose you want to evaluate the limit of $A_n=\sqrt[n]{(1+1).(1+1/2)^2 \cdot (1+1/3)^3\dots (1+1/n)^n}$

One way would be to note the limit of $a_n=(1+1/n)^n = e$, and using AM-GM-HM, you get
$$\frac{n}{\frac1{1+1}+\frac1{(1+1/2)^2}+\frac1{(1+1/3)^3}+\cdots + \frac1{(1+1/n)^n}} \leqslant A_n \leqslant \frac1n\left( (1+1)+(1+1/2)^2+(1+1/3)^3+\cdots +(1+1/n)^n \right)$$
Now the limits on either side evaluate to $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=e$ using [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem_for_the_%E2%88%99/%E2%88%9E_case), so then by the squeeze theorem the required $\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=e$.